# using jQuery to copy column specific form values

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I've used jQuery before to copy billing addresses to shipping addresses, but if I am dynamically generating form rows with various values from PHP, how do I set up the form so that upon a checkmark, a recommended item quantity will be automatically copied *just* to the quantity of the same item?

Here is the basic version of the billing/shipping copy script.

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("input#same").click(function()
    { 
        if ($("input#same").is(':checked')) 
        { 
            // Checked, copy values 
            $("input#qty").val($("input#same").val()); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            // Clear on uncheck 
            $("input#quantity").val(""); 

        } 
    }); 
});
</script>
```

And here is the PHP code dynamically gathering items with their suggested quantity.

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($histresult) )
{
    echo '<tr height = "50px">';


    echo '<td>'.$product_id.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$suggested_quantity.'<input id="same" name="same" type="checkbox" value ="'.$suggested_quantity.'"/> </td>';
    echo '<td><input name="qty" type="text"size="4" maxlength="4"></td>';
    ///Other form elements go here, as well as an Add to Cart Button
}
```

For each item, a suggested wholesale quantity based on a user's favorite items is retrieved from the database.  There is also a text field so that they can enter any amount they want before sending it to their cart.  But if they check the checkbox, I want it to copy that value to the text field.

No only does this code not seem to do the trick, the difference between this and the billing/shipping copy is that now I'm dealing with a dynamic number of fields.  How do I make each individual row achieve this task?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You cannot reuse the same ID on multiple elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery, you would essentially want to grab the suggested value from checkbox and put it in the other form element. Let's say this is your HTML:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         100 <input id="check-1" name="same" type="checkbox" value ="100"/>
             <input id="qty-1" name="qty" type="text"size="4" maxlength="4">
      </td>
      <td>
         100 <input id="check-2" name="same" type="checkbox" value ="100"/>
         <input id="qty-2" name="qty" type="text"size="4" maxlength="4">
      </td>
      <td>
         100 <input id="check-3" name="same" type="checkbox" value ="100"/>
         <input id="qty-3" name="qty" type="text"size="4" maxlength="4">
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

And then this would be your javascript/jQuery:

```
// Bind click event to ALL checkboxes
$("#same-*").live("click", function(e) {

   // Only change it if box is checked
   if( $(this).is(":checked") ) 
   {
      // Get suggested value
      suggested_val = $(this).val();

      // Place in next element (textbox)
      $(this).next().val(suggested_val);       
   }
)};
```

I haven't tested this, but this is basically how it would work.

In your PHP, you would want to dynamically make those ID numbers so each row uses a unique ID. This is usually simple enough to match to your database row id.

```
<td>'.$suggested_quantity.'<input id="same-' . $row->id . '" name="same" type="checkbox" value ="'.$suggested_quantity.'"/> </td>
```

Comment: So the key here is to give each input a unique id.  It can be from the row id or it can be dynamically incremented with each row.  That's a good idea.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code this way

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("input.same").click(function()
    { 
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) 
        { 
            // Checked, copy values 
            var temp = $(this).attr("title");
            $("input#qty"+temp).val($("input#same"+temp).val()); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            // Clear on uncheck 
            $("input#qty"+temp).val(""); 

        } 
    }); 
});
</script>



$i=0;
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($histresult) )
{
    echo '<tr height = "50px">';


    echo '<td>'.$product_id.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$suggested_quantity.'<input class="same" id="same'.$i.'" title="'.$i.'" name="same'.$i.'" type="checkbox" value ="'.$suggested_quantity.'"/> </td>';
    echo '<td><input  class="qty" name="qty'.$i.'" id="qty'.$i.'" type="text"size="4" maxlength="4"></td>';
    ///Other form elements go here, as well as an Add to Cart Button
    $i++;
}
```

Hope this will helpful to you

Comment: please give up to right answer so this answer will helpful to other people also

Comment: The problem with this code was removing the checkbox.  As is, the removal of the number did not happen.  When I added var temp = $(this).attr("title"); above the blank.  It worked.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Recycling IDs/names amongst several html elements is a bad idea I find.

I think it's best to make them unique.

But anyways, here's a suggestion that won't modify your html structure a lot.

Change the form tag as follows:

```
<form id="Order">
...
</form>
```

Change your PHP code as follows (added a label tag to isolate your suggested quantity better in the DOM, got rid of some unnecessary structure for your checkboxes):

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($histresult))
        {
            echo '<tr height = "50px">';


            echo '<td>'.$product_id.'</td>';
            echo '<td><label>'.$suggested_quantity.'<label><input type="checkbox" class="Same"/> </td>';
            echo '<td><input name="qty" id="qty_'.$product_id.'" type="text"size="4" maxlength="4"></td>';
                            ///Other form elements go here, as well as an Add to Cart Button
                   }
```

Finally, here is the jQuery code:

```
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    jQuery("form#Order").click(function(Event){ //One event handler for the form, more efficient that way and you need less html structure to keep track of things
        var Target = jQuery(Event.target); //This is the html element that got clicked on
        if(Target.is("input:checkbox.Same")) //Make sure it's a checkbox that suggests quantity
        {
            var Text = jQuery(Target.closest('tr').children().get(2)).children();   //Get the parent TR tag, get it's third child (td tag containing the text field), get it's child (the text field)
            var Suggested_quantity = Target.prev().html(); //Get the previous sibling which is the label containing the quantity and get it's html content which is the quantity
            if(Target.is(":checked"))
            {
                Text.val(Suggested_quantity);
            }
            else
            {
                Text.val("");
            }
    }); 
});
</script>
```

EDIT: Removed some redundant html code. Added a class to isolate the right checkboxes. Added IDs for the text field (forgot).